# Do not send email activation on public registration while keeping the requireEmailVerification setting on

Tags: users, registration, activation, verification

Is there a way to not send Email Activation on public registrations while keeping the requireEmailVerification setting on.

Because, I have two type of users. The one is the off street registration (no email invite from a member) and the other one is invited.
I want to make the invited users not to receive an Activation Email after registration as  I already activating them in the controller.

Btw, I am just calling the $response = Craft::$app->runAction('users/save-user'); on my controller to handle the registration.

Comment: You might have a simpler time doing this the other way round. Don't require email validation in the Control Panel but enforce it programatically when you need to. [See here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29686/how-to-pragmatically-set-registered-user-status-to-pending-and-then-manually-sen)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change that setting in the Control Panel.
But what you are suggesting is indeed more simple and easy to implement.

Comment: I see. That post should still help you implement what you need hopefully.